# Unit Test Example for Test Driven Development- Should the Assert be AreEqual?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

In the below example of a unit test, the test is attempting to validate the note is created.  Shouldn't the Assert be an "Assert.AreEqual" to verify if the id's match?

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void CreateNoteTest_Pass()
    {
        HomeController target = new HomeController(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        var note = new NotePM();
        note.Text = "This is my test note" + DateTime.Now;
        int id = note.NoteId;
        note.CreatedByUserName = Membership.GetUser("danielle").UserName;

        ActionResult actual;
        actual = target.Create(note);
        Assert.AreNotEqual(id, note.NoteId);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(RedirectToRouteResult));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious to know what the

```
target.create(note)
```

method does. It looks like it takes a NotePM instance and does some work on it (create it in the DB and get the ID, for example).

My guess is that this test is verifying that target.create actually altered note.ID. So it saves the value of note.ID in the variable id, then calls create(note) and asserts that the value of the ID actually changed to some new value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to compare note and actual and verify that they are equal ?

If so, use AreEqual...

Ex:

```
Assert.AreEqual(note, actual, "Note's are not equal.");
```